# Outlook - Delete items from nested folders using Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

Good afternoon all,

Using something similar to the following script is it possible to delete all items from nested folders in Outlook leaving the folders intact. The Structure is

Inbox\@SQLAlerts\Server1

Inbox\@SQLAlerts\Server2

Inbox\@SQLAlerts\Server3

Inbox\@SQLAlerts\Server4

```
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject “Outlook.Application”
$MAPI = $Outlook.getnamespace(“mapi”)
$Inbox = $MAPI.GetDefaultFolder(6)
$SubFolder = $Inbox.Folders | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq “@SQLAlerts”}
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$SubFolder.items | Where-Object {$_.SentOn -lt $date} | ForEach-Object 
{$_.Delete()}
```

Comment: Does this not work?

Comment: It will delete the items from Inbox/@SQLAlerts however I need it to also delete items from Inbox/@SQLAlerts/Server1 subfolder. There is about 40 subfolders under Inbox@SQLAlerts I need to run this on. I am not sure how to add the nested folders.

Comment: Can you do `$subfolder.Folders` and iterate through each?

Comment: Hi Rohin,my Powershell skills are limited, how would this be achieved?

Comment: It would be for all folders under Inbox\@SQLAlerts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line too. It will delete from sub folders.

```
Foreach ($Folder in $SubFolder.Folders)
{
    $ItemsToDelete = $Folder.Items | Where-Object -Property SentOn -LT $date
    foreach ($item in $ItemsToDelete)
    {
        $item.Delete()
    }
}
```

Comment: I thank you for your time Rohin that has worked a treat. Cheers.

Comment: I must tell you that this only works when both outlook and the script are running in the same security context. The script itself calls outlook ensuring both run so. But, for eg, if you have outlook running as a normal user privileges and try to run the script with elevated permissions, i think the script will have trouble talking to some of the outlook objects. Just something to be mindful of.

Comment: Understood, I run Powershell with the same account as my Outlook account.

Comment: I was referring to 'Run as Administrator' option rather than the user account. You could use the same account to run both but 'Run as Administrator' would change the security context.

Answer (score 0):

Initially after testing and removing the date filter I found the script was not removing all items from some of the subfolders, the following resolves this:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject “Outlook.Application”
$MAPI = $Outlook.getnamespace(“mapi”)
$Inbox = $MAPI.GetDefaultFolder(6)
$SubFolder = $Inbox.Folders | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq “@SQLAlerts”}
$SubFolder.items | Out-Null
Foreach ($Folder in $SubFolder.Folders)
{
$ItemsToDelete = $Folder.Items 
foreach ($item in $ItemsToDelete)
{
While ($folder.Items.Count -ne 0)
{
$Folder.Items | % {$_.delete()}
    }
  }
}
```